# Python: How to prompt console input when stdin is occupied?

Tags: python, linux, wget

In an Ubuntu environment, I am hosting a script on a web server and I'm trying to run the script without writing it to a file using the line `wget -O - -o /dev/null 0.0.0.0:8000/myscript | python`

The script starts off running just fine, until I get to a use of `input()` where I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 629, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

I did a little reading on sys.stdin but I'm not finding a clear solution. What can exactly is happening here and how can I work around it?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution here: [Pipe input to Python program and later get input from user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141331/pipe-input-to-python-program-and-later-get-input-from-user)

I added the line `sys.stdin = open("/dev/tty")` and now it seems to work.