# I got 'EOFError: EOF when reading a line' in the execution of my Python code. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, input, stdin, sys

I'm using Python3.8 to make a program that takes an input from the user with the help of `sys.stdin`.
This is the code:

```
import sys

try:    
    file = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
    source = file.read()
    file.close()    
except:
    source = sys.stdin.read()
    
input("\nPress enter to continue... \n")
```

If the user doesn't provide an argument, the program continues with the standard input. The problem is: When I run the program, I get an error at the last line. Here is the output:

```
$ apt-get install google* --print-uris | ./scrFiles/pythonFiles/code.py

Press enter to continue... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./scrFiles/pythonFiles/code.py", line 12, in <module>
    input("\nPress enter to continue... \n")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

What is wrong with my code? :/

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your code. It expects some input because you asked it to (`input("\n...)`). It never gets said input because the piped input doesn't have any more input. So it tells you it received an EOF signal where it expected a line of input

Comment: @PranavHosangadi So how do I use input() command here without errors? Or am I not supposed to use input() and sys.stdin in the same code? I want that last last line to work

Comment: That is correct. When you pipe something into your program, the `stdin` is replaced by the contents of the pipe, so when you do `input(...)`, it expects something but receives nothing. Check this question out:  [Pipe input to Python program and later get input from user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141331/pipe-input-to-python-program-and-later-get-input-from-user)

Comment: An alternative is to only ask for input if you aren't using a pipe, so move your `input(...)` inside the `try` block.