# What is the proper way to accept Prompt AND file from stdin?

Tags: python-click

I've been trying to implement this method: [Pipe input to Python program and later get input from user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141331/pipe-input-to-python-program-and-later-get-input-from-user) in click.

The best I've able to achieve is to initialize `sys.stdin` as `/dev/tty`, and use an eager parameter with a callback function to switch it back:

```py
import sys
import click


stdin = sys.stdin
sys.stdin = open('/dev/tty')

def switch_stdin(ctx, param, value):
    sys.stdin = stdin
    return value

@click.command()
@click.argument('text', type=click.File('rt'))
@click.option('--password', prompt=True, callback=switch_stdin, is_eager=True)
def cli(text, password):
    print(password)
    print('file:')
    for t in text:
        print(t)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

This is not scalable, nor portable (and not elegant). Is there any gracious way to do that in click ?

From the tip of my mind, maybe being able to encapsulate the option execution with a `switch -> handler -> switch back`. Or a `pre-hook`, as opposed to the callback fn.

Comment: You want to switch or control what stdin is connected to from inside the program?  Or you are primarily interested in getting the password from `/dev/tty`? Which part of your solution are you unhappy with?

Comment: @StephenRauch I would like the prompts options and the stdin option to not be required to be in a specific order. The processing of options/parameters in click is tied to multiple things, e.g. command and groups, this current solution because of this current implementation, so it's hardly portable.